# Unrecoverable error handling admin request in wiremock

Tags: docker, wiremock, java-opts

We have wiremock "crashes" when sending big amount of data to create new mappings and I was wondering if there is a way to prevent it. (other way than not sending big amount of data xD)

```
Unrecoverable error handling admin request
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockApp.addStubMapping(WireMockApp.java:243)
        at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.admin.tasks.CreateStubMappingTask.execute(CreateStubMappingTask.java:33)
        at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.AdminRequestHandler.handleRequest(AdminRequestHandler.java:82)
        at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.AbstractRequestHandler.handle(AbstractRequestHandler.java:75)
        at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.servlet.WireMockHandlerDispatchingServlet.service(WireMockHandlerDispatchingServlet.java:142)
        at wiremock.javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1656)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:319)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:273)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:552)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1440)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:505)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1355)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:409)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

We've tried to change java_opts but this doesn't help.

```
-Xms1g
-Xmx2g
```

This is inside docker image (2.35.0) btw.
wiremock doesn't really crashes but as you may expect doesn't work correct either. :)